# Call to undefined method Cake\Controller\Component\RequestHandlerComponent::isMobile()

Tags: cakephp

I am running CakePHP 4.1.6 and referring to this documentation: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html#RequestHandlerComponent::isMobile

I receive the error message:

> Call to undefined method
> Cake\Controller\Component\RequestHandlerComponent::isMobile()

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's outdated information that should have been removed. These methods are not available anymore, you should instead use `\Cake\Http\ServerRequest::is()`:

```php
$isMobile = $this->request->is('mobile');
```

Note that this only works if you have added a `mobile` detector, as it is not part of the core. If you're using the default application template, then it should already be present [**in your dependencies**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/4.2.1/composer.json#L12), and applied [**in your bootstrap**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/4.2.1/config/bootstrap.php#L166-L178).

In `composer.json`:

```json
"require": {
    ...
    "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.8"
},
```

In `config/bootstrap.php`:

```php
ServerRequest::addDetector('mobile', function ($request) {
    $detector = new \Detection\MobileDetect();

    return $detector->isMobile();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. This can happen with a large documentation. Should I open an issue or are you informing the CakePHP team?

Comment: @PeterVARGA You're welcome. I'll get the docs fixed later.